# Feed bots not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chatbot

In the Sci-fi & Fantasy SE chat room, we have [a chat feed bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-24/science-fiction-fantasy) that posts new questions.  However, it hasn't worked in several hours.  The [RSS feed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds) it pulls from is updating, so the issue isn't on that end.  And we're [not alone](https://twitter.com/badp/status/589783718274949120) in this either.

Can someone whack the chat feed bots, and get them working again?

Comment: This is also true of Gaming.

Comment: Yes, a bit of [Percussive Maintenance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/percussive_maintenance) should do the trick!

Comment: The service that manages recurrent tasks seems to have stopped caring about chat.se. Trying to investigate why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The service that handles recurring tasks (of which RSS feed fetching, but also [removing inactive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253918/chat-might-be-forgetting-to-count-people-as-leaving-the-room), is an example), stopped working for chat.stackexchange.com after an API update; unfortunately it stopped in a way that looks like it's working fine, and thus didn't cause any errors to be reported.

Back to working now.

Comment: Suddenly a wave of site questions arrive in the ticker. Thanks!