# Chat might be forgetting to count people as leaving the room

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Usually the chat server will consider you as having left all rooms maybe 10-20 minutes after you close all chat tabs. I don't think Chat has been doing this for a couple of days, and there's several signs of this.

- Whenever I enter a room in the morning, it's the only room I'm in, and I have to join others or click <kbd>Rejoin favorite rooms</kbd>. I didn't have to do that this morning; I was already still connected to all the rooms I was in last night.
- Actually, I was *already in* the list of joined users this morning, very well faded out and on the second line of users. (I have not kept a mobile device connected overnight.)
- The [RPG.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) has an awful lot of lurkers in it, usually these people don't stay connected, and usually we only have maybe a dozen people at a time tops, lurkers included:

[image: about 30 people in the room]

The lurkers go back a full day or more, with that last user on the list showing up as:

[image: seen 1d ago, talked 181d ago]

I don't know if this is localised to RPG.SE's chat rooms or network-wide. Other chat rooms seem to be experiencing a similar malady, but it's hard to tell as I'm less familiar with those.

Comment: Yes, same issues as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253904/feed-bots-not-working#comment829292_253904.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now, see [Feed bots not working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253904/feed-bots-not-working/253922#253922).

Comment: It looks like it has been. Thanks for the fix!