# Our beloved Movie Reel Bot seems to have ceased posting

Tags: bug, chat, feed

I saw this question from April and I wonder if something similar has occurred:

[Feed bots not working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253904/feed-bots-not-working)

The [Movie Reel bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-119/movie-reel) in The Screening Room hasn't posted anything for over [8 hours](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23382773#23382773), despite having several questions added to the site. The [feed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/feeds) seems to be working just fine.

Is it possible that there's an error with the bots again?

Comment: Seems to have been fixed now. :D